# Why is 'cp' failing in this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Here's a snippet of code from a shell script I have written:

```
for src in $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name ${deploy} \! -name gvimrc)
do
    src=$(basename ${src})
    dest="~/.${src}"
    copy="${src} -> ${dest}"
    cp $src $dest && echo -e "${ok} ${copy}" || echo -e "${fail} ${copy}"
done
```

For some reason, `cp` fails to execute. For example, in the case in which `$src='bashrc'`, I get this error:

```
cp: ~/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why this happens, though, because obviously, `~/.bashrc` is the *destination*, not the source, so `cp` shouldn't care whether it exists or not. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Consider using 'eval' - as in: eval cp "$src" "$dest" ... this should ensure the shell expansion occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have escaped the ~ and so it won't get expanded and cp doesn't know how to do it.

With

```
dest=~/".${src}"
```

bash should do it.

Answer (score 10):

Try using `$HOME` instead of `~/` for your home directory.

```
dest="$HOME/.$src"
```

Also, you might want to put quotes around your `$src` and `$dest` variables if you have spaces in **any** of your file names.

```
cp "$src" "$dest" && echo -e "${ok} ${copy}" || echo -e "${fail} ${copy}"
```

Answer (score 7):

"~" is not expanded to your home directory when appearing in double quotes like that. Use `"${HOME}/.${src}"` instead. Also consider using another approach that will work when filenames contain spaces (oh, i just have to think of all my silly mp3 files with their spaces in them!). Instead of doing

```
for src in $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name ${deploy} \! -name gvimrc)
do
    # ...
done
```

Prefer

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name ${deploy} \! -name gvimrc | while read src
do
    # ...
done
```

So by combining @sirlancelots and my space fixes, we get:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 \! -name ${deploy} \! -name gvimrc | while read src
do
    src=$(basename "${src}")
    dest="${HOME}/.${src}"
    copy="${src} -> ${dest}"
    cp "$src" "$dest" && echo -e "${ok} ${copy}" || echo -e "${fail} ${copy}"
done
```